# Fetch API multiple Times and store the result in Array, gives an empty Array ( Vanilla.js )

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an array of area code
const regions = [123,12312,1231231,123123,123123]

and

I have an End Point something like `https:service.org?where=id=${code}`

Data that I get from response looks something like this:

```
features: [{data}]
```

Now All I am trying to do is get the response, store it in the array, and create a JSON File. Here is the snippet of the code, that I have

```
const getResponse = async () => {
 
    let responseData =[]
    regions.forEach(async (code)=> {
        const response = await fetch(`https://services.org?where=id=${code}`); 
        const data = await response.json();
        
        responseData.push(data.features[0])
    })

    console.log(responseData)
}
```

When I console.log the response data it provides me an Empty Array and I am not sure why it is behaving like this.

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't await the calls, so you're logging the array before any of the fetches have returned.

Comment: use `Promise.all()` to wait for many things before continuing.

Comment: Isnt `fetch(`https://services.org?where=id=${code}`); ` returning html instead of json>